# Canonical examples to show that neither $L_p$ or $L_q$ are included in each other?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the Lebesgue measure on $R$. According to many answers on this website, neither

$$
L_p \subseteq L_q \text{ or } L_q \subseteq L_p$$
for $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$.

Showing one is easy, just consider
$$
x^{-1/p}.
$$

However, I am strugling with the other direction. I have tried using exponentials, series and continuous functions to no avail.

Thinking about this, I should be seeking a function that is close to $1$, but sufficiently lower, when raised to the power of $p$ but over $1$ when raised to the power of $q$ .

However, from the searches, the arguments that seem to be presented are for non general $p,q$, for example specific values or saying that there always exist such $p$ and $q$.

**My Question:** Is there a canonical/easy to understand example from which we can see that for a given $p,q$  with $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$ the containment
$$
L_p \subseteq L_q
$$
does not hold?

Comment: Consider functions $ f(x)=(1+x)^{-1/p} $ and $ g(x)=x^{-1/q}\chi_{[-1,1]}(x) $, where $ \chi_{[-1,1]}=1 $ if $ x\in [-1,1] $ and $ 0 $ otherwise. Then for $ p<q $, we have $ f\in L^q $, $ f\notin L^p $ and $ g\in L^p $, $ q\notin L^q $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(note that if $p = q$ then obviously $L_p \subseteq L_q$, so condition should be $1 \leq p \color{red}< q \leq \infty$)

You can't get function that is less than $1$ when raised to the power of $p$ but over $1$ when raised to the power of $q$, as raising to power $q / p$ preserves relation "be less than $1$".

Any function that is bounded by $M$ and integrable in $p$-th power, is also integrable in $q$-th power, because if $|f(x)| < M$ then $|f(x)^q| = |f(x)^p| \cdot |f(x)^{q - p}| \leq |f(x)^p| \cdot M^{q - p}$. So we need to search for an unbounded counterexample.

And this is simply: we know that $x^\alpha$ is integrable near $0$ iff $\alpha > -1$. So we can take $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^\alpha& x \in [0, 1] \\ 0\end{cases}$, such that $\alpha p > -1$ but $\alpha q < -1$. Can you find such $\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, I can, by the archimedian property. Thank you!

Comment: You don't even need archimedian property, as $\alpha$ doesn't have to be rational.

Comment: Hi, of course. Even the density of the reals suffices.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that intuitively you want to find a function that explodes in a bounded portion of the space and is very small (even zero) on the complementary.

Indeed you can adapt the previous example and consider the function f such that $f(x)=x^{-1/q}$ if $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Furthermore it's an easy consequence of Holder's Inequality (or even simpler arguments) that in a space with finite measure $L_q\subseteq L_p$ for all $1\leq p\leq q\leq \infty$.